# How to check with javascript if a drop down has 2 or more options to select?

Tags: javascript

I have a text box that is already showing, but I also have a select box where the user can select a building, and it will show another select box with more options depending on which building the user chose. The second select box always has the option `new`

My problem is that if the user selects a certain building from the select box, the program has to check if the building has more options besides from the `new`option, and if it has, then the text box should disappear, but if the building only has the `new` option, then the textbox must stay there, and the second select box needs to disappear.

I tried using something like:

```
if (secondbox.length==1){
secondbox.style.display='none'}
```

but it works after I changed to another building instead of working instantly.

Javascript:
    if (comm.length == 1){
        comm.style.display='none';
        comm.disabled=true;
        comm.value='';
        comm.style.visibility='hidden';

```
    textNumber.style.visibility='visible';
    textNumber.disabled=false;
    textNumber.focus();

    textic.style.visibility='hidden';
    textic.disabled=true;
    textic.value='';

    document.getElementById('btnComm').value='Add';}
else {
    comm.style.display='';
    comm.disabled=false;
    comm.style.visibility='visible';

    textNumber.style.visibility='hidden';
    textNumber.disabled=true;
    textNumber.value='';

    textic.style.visibility='hidden';
    textic.disabled=true;
    textic.value='';

    document.getElementById('btnComm').value='Update';}
```

}

Comment: Which event handler you have used to handle this? Try to post your HTML and javascript.

Comment: can you post some more code snippets or create a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net). I don't think we have enough information to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I think what @Tariqulazam is getting at is, if your code only works on change, you are probably triggering it with the `onChange` event.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
if(document.getElementById("selectBoxId").childNodes.length >= 2) {
   //The select box has 2 or more options...
}
```